# A balanced binary search tree which is also a heap

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap, binary-search-tree

I'm looking for a data structure where each element in it has two keys. With one of them the structure is a BST and looking at the other one, data structure is a heap. With a little search, I found a structure called [Treap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap). It uses the heap property with a random distribution on heap keys to make the BST balanced!

What I want is a Balanced BST, which can be also a heap. The BST in Treap could be unbalanced if I insert elements with heap Key in the order of my choice.

Is there such a data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Priority Search Tree is the structure which is both a Balanced BST and a Heap. For details see [this paper](http://wwwisg.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/ag/lehre/SS2009/GDS/slides/S10.pdf) or this book: ["Handbook of Data Structures and Applications"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584884355) (Chapter 18.5).

This structure can be used to efficiently search elements that have minimal of all the "heap" keys and "BST" keys in given range.

Comment: It was a little more complex than what I wanted but it helped. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, this answer is somewhat shrouded since both the references are either behind authentication (the paper), or are a paid text (the handbook).